# Redmi note 4 not showing images from cache glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I am loading images using Glide 4.1.1 with disk caching and it's working perfectly on other devices than Red Mi note 4. Red Mi note 4 not showing any cached image. while my emulator and Micromax android one are showing cached images perfectly.

```
 Glide.with(context)
            .load(stringUrl).apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE))
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    viewHolderListener.onLoadCompleted(image, adapterPosition);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    L.d(loadedData.get(adapterPosition).getImagePath());
                    viewHolderListener.onLoadCompleted(image, adapterPosition);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(image);
```

Comment: What OS versions are those? I mean Micromax and Redmi

Comment: @UmangBurman Note 4 is running on Naugat and Micromax is running on Marshmallow

Comment: Is your app installed in the memory card?

Comment: @UmangBurman no

Answer (score 1):

Try and update the glide library to new version

```
    dependencies {
  implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
  }
```

Most important you have to include AppGlide module in your application

```
package com.example.myapp;

import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {}
```

Finally you can enable caching by writing below code:

```
GlideApp.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
  .into(imageView);
```

Refer: [GlideV4 documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/)